# Entity Framework 5: commit does not refresh entity in memory

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework-5, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

i have a big problem.
I'm using Entity Framework 5 and the UnitOfWork pattern (using repositories).
I have an entity object , Person (that inherits from Entity and has got some properties: name,surname, IdAddress (and the virtual entity Address linked with the idAddress).

When i use the following code:

```
Person p = personRepository.FindById(5);
```

i correctly obtain the entity, the foreign is ok, and also entities declared as virtual are loaded.

However, when i use the following code:

```
Person p = new Person();
p.IdAddress = 1;
personRepository.Add(p);
unitOfWork.commit();
```

the entity p has null value for the Address entity.
How can i "force" the refresh of the entity in memory after doing a commit?
Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: (when i try retrieving , in another moment, the entity just persisted by using a FindById, the Address entity is correctly obtained)..so i would like to have a refresh-after-persist behaviour

Answer (score 3):

Use the `Refresh` method of the `ObjectContext`:

```
context.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, p);
```

Or if you're using a `DbContext`:

```
context.Entry<Person>(p).Reload();
```

Comment: i've read about this approach but i have 2 problems: 1) i can't access the context: i have visibility only on the repository and the unitOfWork objects 2) are you sure that, by "reloading" the entity aggregate, i'm sure that all entities composing it are refreshed in a cascade way?

Comment: @user2328912: 1) you can change your repository.Add method so that it reloads the entity; 2) I'm not sure of anything until I tried it ;)

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was re-instantiating the repository right before a page load. Your code will be different but however you generate data in your `personRepository` object from an Entity Framework context, you need to do this each time before the Model is sent to the view.

```
    public ActionResult Form(int id)
    {
        _repository = new EntityFrameworkRepository<Model>(new EntityContext(), "Id");
        return View(_repository.Where(c => c.Id == id).FirstOrDefault() == null ? new Model() : _repository.Where(c => c.Id == id).FirstOrDefault());
    }
```